# How to find if a date falls within a range and return a value in Excel

Tags: date, excel-formula, range, lookup

I have two tables. One contains a list of deliveries with dates over the last year, along with the driver's name. The other table has their name, date they joined a team, date they left a team and the manager name. Most driver's have served with a number of teams.

I'm trying to return the correct manager to table one for the date in the row. So I need to search on the driver's name and the date of the delivery and use that to search in table two to see who the manager was at the time by identifying if the date of delivery falls between the two.

So using the below tables it should check the delivery date against the structure and return "Paul" to the manager Cell.

| Date | Driver | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2022 | Dave | ? |
| 01/08/2022 | Bob | ? |

| Name | join Date | Leave Date | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dave | 01/01/2022 | 01/03/2022 | Ringo |
| Dave | 02/03/2022 | 01/06/2022 | Paul |

I tried using If statements and VLookups but couldn't find a way to combine them that didn't result in a spill error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use the `FILTER`-function to retrieve the manager in column C:

```
=FILTER(tblManager[Manager],
           (tblManager[Name]=[@Driver])*
           (tblManager[join Date]<=[@Date])*
           (tblManager[Leave Date]>=[@Date]),
"- unknown -")
```

---

update for an older Excel version ---

```
=IFNA(INDEX(tblManager[Manager],
       MATCH(1,
          (tblManager[Name]=[@Driver])*
          (tblManager[join Date]<=[@Date])*
          (tblManager[Leave Date]<=[@Date]),0)
 ),"-unknown-")
```

Using a classic INDEX/MATCH combination

---

Multiple AND-criteria can be combined by using the multiply-sign (*).

I used tables called `tblManager` and `tblDriver`
[image]

Comment: Hi Ike, thanks very much for your solution. it looks like you have it cracked on your side! I've copied your formula over and replaced the table and field names, but I'm getting an error that says "The syntax of this name isn't correct". I've had a look a few times and all of the field and table names are correct (although only the tblmanager appears in the formula?). There are colons or semi colons depending on what part of your answer I look at but I've tried both and neither works. Any idea what might be wrong? Thank you again for helping.

Comment: Do you have the FILTER-Function? Check it by typing "=FILTER" into one cell. If FILTER doesn't appear, you have an older version of Excel which doesn't support this method. (I am on a German version therefore semicolon in the screenshot)

Comment: I updated the question with a classic index/match solution - this will work on any version